# How to efficiently compare two maps?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, data-structures

I need to compare 2 maps and I'm looking for the best way to do it. In particular, given two maps in input, I need to determine if at least the 80% of their entries is the same. The current approach is:

-Data is stored in two file in the form of key->value.

For example:

1.1.1.0/24| 178 188 198

1.1.2.0/24| 199 2212 2999 212
....

In this file are stored about 600K entries.

-Entries are uploaded in a map and then the comparison is performed.

The execution is very slow, due to the huge amount of data. (I need to perform this kind of comparison many times). I don't even know if maps are the best data structure to be used. Consider that the number of entries may be different in the 2 files (some present in the first may be not present in the second amd vice versa) and the entries in the file are sorted alphabetically. I'm using Python.

Two different approach:

1)After having uploaded in a set containing tuples the comparison is performed as follows:

```
def checkSame(bgpt1, bgpt2):
    size1 = len(bgpt1)
    size2 = len(bgpt2)

    num_shared_ip = float(len(bgpt1 & bgpt2))
    ratio = num_shared_ip / max(size1, size2)
    return ratio
```

2) using maps the comparison is performed by iteration:

```
def compareMaps(map1,map2):
    counter=0
    for keyM1 in map1:
         if keyM1 in map2:
            if map2[keyM1]==map1[keyM1]:
                counter+=1
    ...
```

Comment: Please show the code of your current approach.

Comment: Just edited., Anyway I don't need an implemantion, just some idea of how I could improve performace

Comment: What’s “very slow” and what would be an acceptable amount of time?

Comment: It has to be just more efficient, no need to reason about the time

Comment: `return num_shared_ip / max(size1, size2)` uses fewer CPython opcodes than `ratio = num_shared_ip / max(size1, size2); return ratio`. There you go – it’s more efficient, just. (*Yes*, you need to reason about the time, I am not asking this for no reason.)

Comment: @RamsesXVII maybe you should make it work correctly before making it work faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your files are sorted, you don’t have to store them or even parse them outside of lines. You can keep advancing in the sequence with the lesser current element:

```
def count_equal(a, b):
    """
    Counts the number of values that are equal in two sorted iterables.

    >>> odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
    >>> primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
    >>> count_equal(odds, primes)
    5
    """
    return _count_equal(iter(a), iter(b))


def _count_equal(a, b):
    c = 0
    x = next(a)
    y = next(b)

    try:
        while True:
            while x < y:
                x = next(a)

            while y < x:
                y = next(b)

            if x == y:
                c += 1
                x = next(a)
                y = next(b)
    except StopIteration:
        return c
```

You can keep track of how many lines there are in each file separately in the same read:

```
from __future__ import division


class CountingIterable:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        count = 0

        for x in self.iterable:
            yield x
            count += 1

        self.count = count


with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a, open('file2.txt', 'r') as b:
    a_counter = CountingIterable(a)
    b_counter = CountingIterable(b)

    a_iterator = iter(a_counter)
    b_iterator = iter(b_counter)

    n = count_equal(a_iterator, b_iterator)

    # consume any remaining elements to acquire count
    for _ in a_iterator: pass
    for _ in b_iterator: pass

    result = n / max(a_counter.count, b_counter.count)
```

Comment: Simple merge for the win!

Answer (score 0):

Since you post no code I could try to suggest some ideas.

Maybe you could try to [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) the two files and then compare every line with the next one (this needs that every file has a unique key). For every hit you could update the counter by one and when you end up at the file end, you divide with the lines count to get the similarity.

Another idea is computing Jaccard Similarity but this requires that each file has unique values and that your data fit to memory. Read all the values from both files and create (key:value) sets of strings. (Set means that the cardinality of each value is one). Then you could use this function:

```
def compute_jaccard_index(set_1, set_2):
    n = len(set_1.intersection(set_2))    
    return n / float(len(set_1) + len(set_2) - n)
```

to return a normalized index [0 - 1] on how similar are the two sets.

**EDIT:** Just saw your posted code. Try [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) on the tuples set as I suggested. You can also use one of the [ready implementations for Jaccard Index](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.jaccard_similarity_score.html)